# How do I correct generate URL with AJAX + pushState?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html, dom

The kind of problem is: When I'm switching into pages, about/index.html or skills/index.html, old alias URL didn't remove.
[image]
[image]
As far as you can see, if I go to the next link, I'll get /about/skills ... but it's not the correct path. I'm using Ajax + pushState.

```js
$(document).on('click', '#nav_bar nav a,.flat-button, a.logo', function ( e ) {

   e.preventDefault();

   if ( !$(this).hasClass('active') ) {

   if ( app.ui.pageLoad($(this).attr('href'), $(this).attr('rel')) ) {
      debug;
      $('#nav_bar nav a.active').removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');

      window.history.pushState("", "", $(this).attr('href'));
   }


   }

   $('a.logo').removeClass('active');

   e.stopPropagation();

   return false;
   });
```

```js
pageLoad: function ( url, rel ) {

   console.log(url);

   if ( app.ajax !== null ) {

   return false;

   }
   else {

   app.ui.preloader.preloaderInit(rel);


   app.ajax = jQuery.ajax({
   type: 'GET',
   url: url
   });

   app.ajax.done(function ( msg ) {
   var cont = $(msg).filter("#page");
   app.ui.contents = cont.contents();

   app.ajax = null;
   });

   app.ajax.fail(function ( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
   const errmsg = 'Error';
   $("#page").html(errmsg);

   });


   return true;

   }


   },
```

Comment: what does a.href value looks like?

Comment: <a rel="index" href="index.html" class="home-link active"><i class="icon-hom"></i></a> <a
   rel="about" href="about/index.html" class=""><i class="icon-prof"></i></a> <a rel="skills"
                                                                                       href="skills/index.html"
                                                                                       class=""><i
   class="icon-gear"></i></a> <a rel="gallery" href="portfolio/index.html" class=""><i
   class="icon-eye"></i></a> <a rel="contact" href="contact/index.html" class=""><i class="icon-mail"></i></a>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed issue 
app.ajax = jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'http://localhost:63342/jacekjeznach.com/' + url
         });

Answer (score 0):

Use root relative paths (they start with a `/`) instead of relative paths (they are resolved relative to the current file location):

`href="skills/index.html" => href="/skills/index.html"`

Comment: @НиколайКузьмин it might be because looking at your screenshots you are serving your site from a subfolder `/jacek...`

Comment: I think the problem is here:
if ( app.ui.pageLoad($(this).attr('href'), $(this).attr('rel')) ) {
      $('#nav_bar nav a.active').removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');

      window.history.pushState("", "", $(this).attr('href'));
   }

Comment: I just opened with Webstorm, it's not subf

Comment: Can you help me via skype? nickolay.kuzmin1

Comment: @НиколайКузьмин why is this `/jacek...` thing in your address bar? (on your screenshots)

Comment: I just opened with Webstorm, it's not subf